# What is a TAI64 time format?

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, time-format

While going through the Logstash date plugin documentation at

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match

I came across `TAI64N` date format.

Can someone please explain about this time format?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TAI stands for Temps Atomique International, the current international real-time standard. One TAI second is defined as the duration of `9,192,631,770` periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium atom. TAI also specifies a frame of reference.

From [Toward a Unified Timestamp with explicit precision](https://www.demographic-research.org/volumes/vol12/6/12-6.pdf)

TAI64 defines a 64-bit integer format where each value identifies a particular SI second. The duration of SI seconds is defined through a known, precise count of state transitions of a cesium atom. Time is structured as a sequence of seconds starting January 1, 1970 in the Gregorian calendar, when atomic time (TAI) became the international standard for real time. The standard defines 2<sup>62</sup> seconds before the year 1970, and another 2<sup>62</sup> from this epoch onward, thus covering a span of roughly 300 billion years, enough for most applications.

**The extensions TAI64N and TAI64NA allow for finer time resolutions by
referring to particular nanoseconds and attoseconds (10<sup>-18</sup>s), respectively, within a particular second.**

While TAI64 is compellingly simple and consistent, it has to be extended not only
with regard to fine resolutions, but in other ways as well.

- It is only concerned with time-points, but a complete model of time needs to address the interrelation of time-points and intervals as well. Most models conceive intervals as sets of consecutive timepoints. This creates the obvious transformation problem - assuming a dense time domain - that no amount of time-points with a postulated duration of 0 can yield an interval with a duration larger than 0, and that even the shortest interval is a set of an infinite number of time-points.
- TAI64 does not address uncertainty with respect to time.
- It emphasizes monotonically-increasing continuity of time measurement. Human perception of time, however, is shaped by less regular astronomical phenomena.

Precisely, TAI64 format is better for various reasons such as,

- International Atomic Time
- Strictly monotonic (no leap seconds)
- 64-bit uint #seconds from epoch
- **32-bit uint #nano-seconds (TAI64N)**
- 32-bit uint #atto-seconds (TAI64NA)

You can read further on, [Bernstein D.J. 2002. "TAI64, TAI64N, and TAI64NA](http://cr.yp.to/libtai/tai64.html),

> **TAI64, TAI64N, and TAI64NA**
>
> **TAI and real time**
>
> TAI64 labels and external TAI64 format. A TAI64 label is an integer
> between 0 and 2^64 referring to a particular second of real time.
> Integer `s` refers to the TAI second beginning exactly `2^62 - s` seconds
> before the beginning of 1970 TAI, if `s` is between 0 inclusive and 2^62
> exclusive; or the TAI second beginning exactly `s - 2^62` seconds after
> the beginning of 1970 TAI, if `s` is between 2^62 inclusive and 2^63
> exclusive. Integers 2^63 and larger are reserved for future
> extensions. Under many cosmological theories, the integers under 2^63
> are adequate to cover the entire expected lifetime of the universe; in
> this case no extensions will be necessary. A TAI64 label is normally
> stored or communicated in external TAI64 format, consisting of eight
> 8-bit bytes in big-endian format. This means that `bytes b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7` represent the label `b0 * 2^56 + b1 * 2^48 + b2 * 2^40 + b3 * 2^32 + b4 * 2^24 + b5 * 2^16 + b6 * 2^8 + b7`.
>
> For example, `bytes 3f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff hexadecimal` represent the
> second that ended 1969 TAI; `bytes 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 hexadecimal`
> represent the second that began 1970 TAI; `bytes 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 hexadecimal` represent the following second. `Bytes 40 00 00 00 2a 2b 2c 2d hexadecimal` represent `1992-06-02 08:07:09 TA`I, also known as
> `1992-06-02 08:06:43 UTC`.

[source](https://cnmat.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/attachments/OSC-for-PARLAB.pdf)